# Unity how to make raycaster test only against collider in frustum

Tags: unity, raycasting, collider, frustum

I'm working on a scene with thousands of object wich have all a collider associated. I'm just testing if my mouse is on top of any collider in a 2D space. The raycasting operation is taking a lot of time (2 ms for a thousand objects) I suspect the stock unity raycaster is testing against every collider even if they are not inside the frustum any way to change that while still using unity raycasting solution?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your specific application/use case? There might be domain-specific optimizations we can apply that will give you bigger efficiency wins.

Comment: This a force-directed graph display i'm working on, i want every node and edge to be clickable via my mouse, at the moment i'm using Button from the UI base asset as node, and lineRenderer + 2dPolygonCollider for my edges, the collision are polled by the unity event system created with the interface's canvas.

Comment: Ah. This use case has the benefit that the closest objects to the pointer in one frame are very frequently objects that were close on the previous frame, so you may want to take advantage of that to narrow your search space for small cursor movements.

Answer (score 2):

Unity definitely has some spatial partitions of their own under the hood of all their physics and raycasting systems, it's very unlikely Unity's actually doing a collision check with every single collider in your scene whenever you cast a ray.

How much you optimize from here depends on how constrained your problem is, and how much work you want to put into creating new systems with those constraints in mind.

###### Here's a couple of suggestions

###### 3D raycasting

If you have to keep things in 3D with proper raycasting, try reducing the complexity of your colliders, avoid using MeshColliders in favour of box and sphere colliders. Try adding all the objects that you want to raycast against to their own separate layer and filtering out all other layers when you do a cast. Prefer RaycastNonAlloc to RaycastAll so that you're not allocating new memory that will have to be cleaned up.

###### 2D raycasting

If you're doing everything in 2D, axis-aligned space, then you don't need to use raycasting at all. You can prefer 2D overlap tests, by leveraging Physics2D.OverlapPointNonAlloc or by creating your own simple tests (and spatial partitions). Again, prefer box colliders (AABB tests) and circle colliders over complex colliders, and employ filters on raycast calls.

###### Custom, Jobified

If none of this is enough, raycasting is necessary to your game and you can't amortize the costs via creative design somehow... then I'd recommend creating your own system which collects unity transform and collider data into some NativeArrays, then you can do your own raycast-like thing off the main thread, leveraging multiple cores, cache coherence and the burst compiler.

Comment: Thanks for you insightful suggestions, I'm in a 2d space working with box BUT not axis-aligned and I'm just looking to see if my mouse is over some object, I'm seriously thinking to create my own framework to manage this. Any suggestion how to detect if my mouse is over a rectangle shape but in any rotation?

Comment: You would probably have to go with some separating axis-theorem based algo in that case. I guess you could find the change of basis matrix to transform an arbitrary box rotation into something axis aligned, then use that on the mouse position to get into aligned-space, then you might be able to perform an AABB on that. I've never tried nor heard of this method before though so I'm not certain this would be possible or faster.

Comment: Personally I was love any excuse to do things myself, always a learning journey whether or not it works out in the end. Good luck!